# Wix Toolset - Best practice for config file?

Tags: c#, wix

I've got a project that before it can be run the appsettings.json file must be configured correctly.

So far I've googled for a while and was unable to find a solution.
I have used heat to migrate the required dlls over to the install directory.
To edit this json file I originally:

1. Created a Custom Action to serialize models into the appsettings.json file but for some reason this custom action was causing an error that I couldn't debug (Googled and found 3 different solutions, but sadly none of them were able to help me)
2. I have decided to open the json file after installation, which works but I am unable to find a way to have the notepad opened as admin to edit the json file(I have already tried a bunch of solutions for this one too)

Which solution should pursue? Maybe I'm just bad at googling for solutions but maybe some insight as for which solution would be best practice would help.

**Product.wxs**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- The name of the product -->
<?define Name = "xxx" ?>
<!-- The manufacturer, for setup package publisher and folder info -->
<?define Manufacturer = "xxx" ?>
<!-- The version number of this setup package-->
<?define Version = "1.0.0" ?>
<!-- UpgradeCode must be unique and not changed once the first version of the program is installed. -->
<?define UpgradeCode = "{145ED92C-BA1B-4257-8791-2337A012EEE7}" ?>
<?if $(var.Platform) = x64?>
<?define bitness = "(64 bit)"?>
<?define Win64 = "yes"?>
<?define PlatformProgramFilesFolder = "ProgramFiles64Folder" ?> 
<?else ?>
<?define bitness = "(32 bit)"?>
<?define Win64 = "no"?>
<?define PlatformProgramFilesFolder = "ProgramFilesFolder" ?>
<?endif ?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="$(var.Name) $(var.bitness)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)" Version="$(var.Version)" Language="1033">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallPrivileges="elevated"/>

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version of [ProductName] is already installed. Setup will now exit." />
        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="xxx.xxx.xxx.WindowsService.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

        <Feature Id="MainApplication" Title="Main Application" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="$(var.xxx.xxx.xxx.WindowsService.TargetFileName)" />
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="HeatGenerated"/>
        </Feature>

        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="$(var.PlatformProgramFilesFolder)">
                <Directory Id="ROOTDIRECTORY" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)">
                    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.Name)" />
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Component Id="$(var.xxx.xxx.xxx.WindowsService.TargetFileName)" Win64="$(var.Win64)" Guid="FD94EF3C-4A0B-4102-AF1E-2A489B4DB7DF">
                <RemoveFile Id="ALLFILES" Name="*.*" On="both" />
                <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller"
                                Type="ownProcess"
                                Name="xxx.xxx.xxx.WindowsService"
                                Account="LocalSystem"
                                DisplayName="$(var.Name)"
                                Description="Deployment agent for xxx"
                                Start="auto"
                                Interactive="yes"
                                Vital="yes"
                                ErrorControl="critical"
                                Arguments="/start xxx.xxx.xxx.WindowsService"/>
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
        <UIRef Id="SetupDialogUI" />

        <Binary Id="bgPic" SourceFile="images/bg.bmp"/>
        <Binary Id="cancelbtn" SourceFile="images/cancelbtn.bmp"/>
        <Property Id="Cancel">cancelbtn</Property>

        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action='xxx.xxx.xxx.WindowsService.CustomAction' After='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

**Error Log From MSI**

```
MSI (c) (10:64) [15:11:16:149]: Note: 1: 1723 2: xxx.xxx.xxx.WindowsService.CustomAction 3: SaveAppsettings 4: C:\Users\vsun\AppData\Local\Temp\MSIFC10.tmp 
MSI (c) (10:64) [15:11:16:149]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (10:64) [15:11:16:149]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1723 
MSI (c) (10:64) [15:11:16:149]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (10:64) [15:11:16:149]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2867 
DEBUG: Error 2867:  The error dialog property is not set
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2867. The arguments are: , , 
MSI (c) (10:64) [15:11:16:154]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

Error 1723. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action xxx.xxx.xxx.WindowsService.CustomAction, entry: SaveAppsettings, library: C:\Users\vsun\AppData\Local\Temp\MSIFC10.tmp 
MSI (c) (10:64) [15:11:17:024]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (10:64) [15:11:17:024]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
MSI (c) (10:64) [15:11:17:024]: Product: xxx xxx xxx (32 bit) -- Error 1723. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action xxx.xxx.xxx.WindowsService.CustomAction, entry: SaveAppsettings, library: C:\Users\vsun\AppData\Local\Temp\MSIFC10.tmp 

Action ended 15:11:17: xxx.xxx.xxx.WindowsService.CustomAction. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (10:64) [15:11:17:025]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (10:64) [15:11:17:025]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2896 
DEBUG: Error 2896:  Executing action xxx.xxx.xxx.WindowsService.CustomAction failed.
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2896. The arguments are: xxx.xxx.xxx.WindowsService.CustomAction, ,
```

**Custom Action**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.Models;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace xxx.xxx.xxx.WindowsService.CustomAction
{
    public class CustomAction
    {
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult SaveAppsettings(Session session)
        {
            // Pull values from installer
            string keyVaultConnectionString = session["KeyVaultConnectionString"];
            string keyVaultUrl = session["KeyVaultUrl"];


            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if the xxx makes it confusing. For security reasons I have to replace some of the context.

Comment: Creating custom action is the way to go. Please paste your wix code, CA code and the error that you are getting.

Comment: If the config file is XML file, then you could have used XMLFILE ELEMENT, but since its JSON custom action is the way to go.

Comment: @Isaiah4110 I added the code from Product and the Error log from the MSI, for the CA all it does right now is take in inputs. If there is something else that you need to better understand what my problem is please let me know

Comment: So the custom action is failing, that's all I can understand from this. Can you paste the CA code as well? I need to understand whats going on within the CA.

Comment: Okay sorry about that, I just added the CA code

Comment: Do you have your custom action (xxx.xxx.xxx.WindowsService.CustomAction) defined in a separate file?

Comment: yes, I have it defined in my Input dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looks like you are not including your custom action dll within your wix code. Please try the following and make sure to include your CA dll. Edit the CA dll name/entry point etc to match your code.

```
    <Fragment>
      <CustomAction Id='xxx.xxx.xxx.WindowsService.CustomAction' BinaryKey='CA123' DllEntry='SaveAppsettings' Execute='immediate'
                    Return='check'/>

      <Binary Id='CA123' SourceFile='xxx.xxx.xxx.WindowsService.CustomAction.dll'/>
   </Fragment>
```

Comment: Hey I found the problem. I wasn't using makesfxca.exe on my dll to get the ca.dll that I needed. Though I'm not sure how to get this to run with Visual Studio instead of having to run it through command line everytime I build the custom action.

Comment: @boboobobo the Wix.CA.targets file defines a "PackCustomAction" target. If you just made a regular c# project in Visual studio it won't be importing this targets file. Two options are to re-make the project as a "WiX Toolset > C# Custom Action Project for WiX v#" or to manually insert the import into your existing project. Probably just creating the project itself and just moving/copy&paste your code into the new project would be fastest.This will let your build automatically run makesfxca.exe on the custom action dll.

Comment: That's the interesting thing. The CA project is a "C# Custom Action Project For Wix v3" and the custom action dll that it creates causes the installer to have a DLL issue. But when I run the Makesfxca myself with the parameters, and use that in the installer there are no problems at all. Though right now I'm having an issue where my service isn't being added to the registry for some reason so I need to take a step back and I can't ask questions on SO anymore because of their rules